# How to sort through table using a sublist of criteria in excel

Tags: excel, list, sorting

I have a table of data with 5 columns A B C D E. Under column A are values ranging from 1 to 1000 (with repeats and no blanks), and columns B to E have data relating to that number. How do I sort this table if I have a predefined list in mind, let's say I want to see only the data relating to numbers 5, 8, 15, 100, 150...etc. How would I be able to sort it with a custom list?

Let me know if further clarification is needed.

Comment: Is column A sorted already, and do the blanks in column A correspond with duplicates of the above value (i.e. for rows 5-12, row 5 has "8" and rows 6-12 have a blank to indicate they refer to "8")?

Comment: @Archmage i meant to write no blanks. all good tho, I figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution after tinkering around.

I went into into data > advanced and selected my whole table ($A$1:$E$2000) as the "List range" and put down my list of criteria (the numbers I'm sorting for from column A) in column F as the "Criteria range". You need to enter A's header as the header of your list of criteria or else it won't work.